# Limit question about continuity of a given floor function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

If $f(x)= \left[\frac{3 \sin x}{x}\right] $ where $\left[ . \right]$ denotes the greatest integer function. For $x \neq 0$ , find the value of $f(0)$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$

I tried solving it using Sandwich theorem but the limits aren't equal

Comment: Try with a different method: the left hand limit does equal the right hand limit in this case

Comment: Consider that for x close to 0, whether on the left or the right, sin(x)/x is close to but slightly less than 1...what does that mean about $[3\sin(x)/x]$?

Comment: @Ian Got it It will be some value less than 3 but greater than 2 so the limit will equal 2 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By the Mean Value Theorem, $$\frac{3\sin x-3\sin 0}x=3\cos\xi$$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.